# Rails 7 send mail in production returns mail.delivery_method error undefined method `merge'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

When I try to send any mail in production I get the following error.

```
gems/actionmailer-7.0.2.3/lib/action_mailer/delivery_methods.rb:65:in `wrap_delivery_behavior': undefined method `merge' for "25bcae06-5520-46c5-b1a4-83e6828df6c4":String (NoMethodError)

            mail.delivery_method(klass, (send(:"#{method}_settings") || {}).merge(options || {}))
                                                                           ^^^^^^
```

This error happens on every mailer, however to test this I used the following code in the console as a demonstration.

```
ActionMailer::Base.mail(
  from: "test@example.co", 
  to: "valid.recipient@domain.com", 
  subject: "Test", 
  body: "Test"
).deliver_now
```

Im using the following two gems which affect email. `Roadie-rails` `postmark-rails`.

I'm only using the Postmark gem in production.

In dev I'm able to send emails no problem.  However, in production I get the above error.

What am I missing here? Why do I get this error only in production?

Comment: From the error I can tell, that `send(:"#{method}_settings")` is returning a string, but rails expect it to return an object. But I am not sure how this can happen, or where this method is defined.

Comment: I checked https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration and it looks like something like `smpt_settings` might be defined in your `production.rb` - and pointing to "25bcae06-5520-46c5-b1a4-83e6828df6c4" instead of an object containing settings.

Comment: I've removed Postmark from the app and switched to regular SMTP from a normal email account. This fixed the issue.